# dhtmlxGrid : Cliclking header in Big Data grid

Tags: dhtmlx

I'd like to maintain page location while click onto header.
But if I'm in page 5 and click onto header then page location changed to 1 page.
(sort is perfect) 
I want maintain my page location if I click onto header in page 5, still maintain location
5 page and sorting is perfectly.

I think this is not enough to explain my situation. So I post my development environment

I'm using struts2 and mysql. and here's my javascript.

```
function fnGridInitSW(){
swgrid = new dhtmlXGridObject('swGridBox');
swgrid.setImagePath("../../../common/img/dhtmlx/grid/");
swgrid.setHeader("SoftWareName, company, version, Install_date");
swgrid.setColumnIds(
    "COL_1"
    +",COL_2"
    +",COL_3"
    +",COL_4"
);
swgrid.setInitWidthsP("25,25,25,*");
swgrid.setColTypes("ro,ro,ro,ro");
swgrid.setColSorting("str,str,str,str");

swgrid.attachEvent("onXLS", function(){
    $("#swnotfound").hide();
    $("#swgridLoading").show();
});
swgrid.attachEvent("onXLE", function(){
    $("#swgridLoading").hide();
    swgrid.changePage(chPg);
    $("#swnotfound").hide();
});
swgrid.init();
swgrid.attachEvent("onBeforePageChanged",function(ind,count){
    chPg = count;
    if (!swgrid.getRowsNum()){
        return false;
    };
    return true;
}); 
var mygrid_state = swgrid.getSortingState();
popFnSearch(swgrid.getColumnId(mygrid_state[0]), mygrid_state[1]);  
// Custom Sorting
swgrid.attachEvent("onBeforeSorting",function(ind, type, direction) {
    popFnSearch(swgrid.getColumnId(ind), direction);
    var sInd;
    var mygrid_state = swgrid.getSortingState(); 
    if( typeof(mygrid_state[0]) == "undefined" ){
        sInd = ind;
    }
    direction = (mygrid_state[1] == "des") ? "asc": "des";
    swgrid.setSortImgState(true,sInd,direction); 
    return true;
    });
}
function popFnSearch(sortC, sortD) {
    if( typeof(sortC) == "undefined" ) sortC = swgrid.getColumnId(3); 
    if( typeof(sortD) == "undefined" ) sortD = "desc";

    var params = "/url/Info.do?"&sortC="+sortC+"&sortD="+sortD+"&pageCnt=5";
    swgrid.clearAndLoad(params);
}
```

here's my xml for grid.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/xml; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<rows total_count='<s:property value="%{totalCnt}" />' pos='<s:property value="%{posStart}" />'>        
    <s:if test="softwareList.size > 0">
        <s:iterator value="%{softwareList}" status="index">
            <row id="'index<s:property value='%{SW_SEQNO}'/>'">                                      
                <cell><s:property value="%{SW_NM}" /></cell> 
                <cell><s:property value="%{SW_COMPANY}" /></cell> 
                <cell><s:property value="%{SW_VER}" /></cell>               
                <cell class="last"><s:property value="%{INST_DT}" /></cell>
            </row>
        </s:iterator>
    </s:if> 
</rows>
```

here's my query

```
//get total count from softwarelist
<select id="getSoftwareInfoTotCnt" resultClass="Integer" parameterClass = "d">
    SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0) 
    FROM T_PC_SW_LIST sl 
    JOIN T_SOFTWARE so ON sl.SW_SEQNO = so.SW_SEQNO
</select>
//get real data from softwarelist
<select id="getSoftwareInfo" resultClass="c" parameterClass = "d">
    SELECT 
    sl.SW_SEQNO 
    , sl.ASST_SEQNO 
    , so.SW_NM 
    , so.SW_COMPANY 
    , so.SW_VER
    , DATE_FORMAT(sl.INST_DT, '%Y-%m-%d') AS INST_DT
    FROM T_PC_SW_LIST sl 
    JOIN T_SOFTWARE so ON sl.SW_SEQNO = so.SW_SEQNO
        ORDER BY $sortC$ $sortD$
        LIMIT #posStart# , #count#
</select>
```

If anyone have solution please help me..

Answer (score 1):

You may get the current active page before the sorting started using the getStateOfView() method:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid:api_method_dhtmlxgridobject_getstateofview

and then open the needed page after the new sorted data is loaded using the changePage() method:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid:api_method_dhtmlxgridobject_changepage